# Mushroom Wars 2 - hero collection

Tags: mushroom-wars-2

How do you get more heroes? I've got the original Rudo and somehow I wound up with Pahom. I don't know how to get the rest?!?

I bought the full campaign, but specifically I'm asking about heroes for online multiplayer. I think it's something to do with getting each hero's souls, but I'm not sure how?

Comment: Made the tag for you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did want to mention this is for Android, because the game is slightly different on PC than for mobile. I'm not even sure if iOS is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I got this response by asking [MushroomWarsUniverse](https://www.facebook.com/MushroomWarsUniverse):

> Hi!
>
> To unlock heroes you need to collect their souls from chests and by defeating players in multiplayer mode.